# Accessing K8S Service in AWS Private Subnet not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

Scenario in AWS EKS Service:

1. Pods are running on service "web-ui-svc" in public subnet
2. Another pods were running on service "web-api-svc" which is in private subnet
3. Created Ingress for "web-ui", say "web-ui-ing"
   Now Ingress "web-ui-ing" routes trafic to "web-ui-svc".
   Expected:
   "web-ui-svc" pods wants to communicate "web-api-svc" on port 1000 for API calls.

   I tried by passing ENV like "web-api-svc:1000". Not working. But i could curl inside the Node.

   Also when i access ingress url of "web-ui-ing", UI page is comming up but connectivity to web-api-svc is not happening..

Note: Both subnets are in same VPC which EKS Cluster using.

Do i need to configure proxy?, to route traffic to corresponding svc?

**web-ui YAML(in AWS public subnet):**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web-ui
  namespace: web
  name: web-ui
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: web-ui
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/net: "true"
        io.kompose.service: web-ui
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: WEB_API_ENDPOINT
              value: "http://web-api:1000"
          image: ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/web/ui:latest
          name: web-ui
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      nodeSelector:
        web_group: "web_group"
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web-ui
  namespace: web
  name: web-ui
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "3000"
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: web-ui
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**web-api.yaml(in AWS Private Subnet)**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web-api
  namespace: web
  name: web-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: web-api
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/webui_net: "true"
        io.kompose.service: web-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/webapi:latest
          name: web-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1000
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      nodeSelector:
        web_api_group: "web_api_group"
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web-api
  namespace: web
  name: web-api
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "1000"
      port: 1000
      targetPort: 1000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: web-api
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Do i need to create Proxy kind of thing here?

Comment: Share your deployment, service, ingress yamls

Comment: thanks in advance and updated